# Avoid two passes over a list of validators

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

I am validating the parameters passed to a series of commands in a file using the following code:

```
            for (Parameter p : s.getCommand(idx).getParameters()) {
                for (ValidationFactory.TYPES validationType : ValidationFactory.TYPES.values()) {
                    validator = ValidationFactory.getValidator(validationType, errors);
                    try {
                        validator.validate(p);
                    } catch (ValidationException e) {
                        Report.logErrorMessage("Failed to validate: " + validationType);                            
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Then in the ValidationFactory I have:

```
public final class ValidationFactory {

public enum TYPES {
    PROPERTIES, 
    PORTS
};

private ValidationFactory() {
}

public static AbstractValidator getValidator(TYPES validationType,
        ValidationErrors errors) {
    switch (validationType) {
    case PROPERTIES:
        return new PropertiesValidator(errors);
    case PORTS:
        return new PortRangeValidator(errors);
    default:
        return null;
    }
}}
```

This code works really nicely and allows for new validators to be added at a later date. There is one relatively minor problem though...

The outer for loop iterates over a list of parameters that will be passed to the command, while the inner for loop iterates over a list of validators which can do the validation. Depending on the parameter however, it may not be necessary to continue the validation with the second validator, the first one may have already done the work... So, PropertiesValidator might have done the work needed, and now there is no need to call the second validator, but it is going to call it anyway. I guess I could use a variable to maintain validation state, and then it could skip if already done.. both validators extend an AbstractValidator class which would be the best place for this.

I would like to do the validation in one pass while keeping the structure of the Factory pattern. I was thinking of putting in some sort of delegator class.. I am using java 1.6 so I can't switch on string arguments which would be nice.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "which means there are two passes over the list of parameters. I would like to do the validation in one pass while keeping the structure of the Factory pattern"

Comment: Sorry, I have now reworded the entire question... hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a Generic Validator, which is going to be common to all the validator, and define specific validation in properties and port validation. So now there is no duplication of validation by moving common logic into generic validator and specific validation in others.

Comment: thanks for you answer, yes - i think you are right. I actually already had a generic validator in AbstractValidator, but wasn't using it as much as I could have. There will be still be two passes but the cost of continuing the validation will be minimal.